# .NET assembly consumed by classic ASP works once then throws ObjectRefNotSetException

Tags: c#, .net, com, asp-classic, exception

I have created a .NET assembly in VS2010 for a Vendor web app in Classic ASP to consume.

- The assembly is compiled for .NET 3.5 (which is on the DEV computer)
- I have a Local IIS Dev pc running windows XP Pro with IIS 5.1
- I have set the assembly to "Make Com Visible"
- The Build is set to "Register for COM Interop"
- On the dev machine i register the dll using regasm mydll.dll /codebase
- On the dev machine i granted the IUSR and IWAM user accounts read access to the registry `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones`

What is happening is the assembly is used during login validation to lookup user types that define the layout of pages based on their type.  The asp works fine the first time after is sign in and returns the type with no errors.  But if i logout or close the page and log back in, the ASP throws an error at my com object of Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object.  Almost like the GC is not picking up the object after it completes the registration.  The Object is not set as Global object and is only used at validation of Login page.  I have tried disposing and not disposing in the classic ASP page and get the same results.

I am at a loss as to what i need to do to resolve this issue.  I have spent the last 3 days reading through examples and topics on the subject, but i have not come across anyone else with the same issue.  Any ideas, help or things to try would be greatly appreciated.

This is The Assembly Main

```
namespace rd_custom
{
    [ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), EventTrackingEnabled]
    public class rd_Custom
    {
        private rd_Logger rdLog;
        private XmlDocument DADoc;

        public String getRequesterType(String reqId, String dbProf)
        {
            //"Logic is Here to do user Lookups"

            rd_sqlCon rdCon = new rd_sqlCon();
            rdCon.rdLog = rdLog;     // This is Disposed and Set to null later as well
            rdCon.LoadSqlConfig(dbProf, "requester_type");
            String[] parms = new String[1];
            parms[0] = "requester_id|" + reqId;
            DataTable dt = rdCon.builDataTable(parms);
            rdCon.Dispose();   //*Answer
            rdCon = null;      //Previously was setting to null

            return strRequesterType;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Classic ASP referencing the COM

```
Dim ls_requester_type
Dim rdCustomObj
Set rdCustomObj = Server.CreateObject("rd_custom.rd_custom")
*Err*ls_requester_type = rdCustomObj.getRequesterType(CStr(l_l_requester_id), CStr(l_s_db_profile))*
If ls_requester_type <> "ERROR" Then
    Session("RequesterType") = ls_requester_type
End If
Set rdCustomObj = nothing
```

Comment: Can you mark the line of code where "ASP throws an error at my com object of Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object" ?

Comment: I added *Err* at the beginning of the line that throws the Object error.

Comment: If there were problems loading the com object I would exepct it to fail on the CreateObject call. Have you verifed that l_l_requester_id and l_s_db_profile variables are defined when the call fails ?

Comment: @user957902 Yes i have verified that the l_l_requester_id and l_s_db_profile contain values.  There would be issues in many other parts of the site if they didn't.  Those are both session variables that are set locally for each page.

Comment: My gut instinct here is that the execption is begin thrown inside your getRequesterType method, somwhere in the .Net code. Do you have any try catch blocks in the implementation of the method ?

Comment: @user957902 Yes i do have try catch blocks in my assembly that logs any errors and also, i set some debug variable both log to a local file.  It is logging the variables when the object is set the first time with no errors.  The second time my Object is called, it fails not even being able to call the getRequesterType method, i believe because my rdCustomObj is never really set, hence the error.

Comment: ASP is interpreted so its going to be using the IDispatch interface to indirectly call your method. I would try and overided the IDispatch methods created for your object (AutoDual) and hook some loging in there to see if its even getting that far. I really think the exception is being thrown in managed code somewhere. Com uses unmanged pointers. If something goes wrong there, you ususually don't get a clean exception like that. More like a memory access violation.

Comment: A half hour of research reveals that you can't easily hook into the auto generated IDispatch interface implementation.

Comment: Hmmm... That EventTrackingEnabled atrribute appears to be for COM+. You might try taking that out, and seeing if the behavior changes.

Comment: @user957902 Ok, so i have tried a couple of things I changed ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual to be ClassInterfaceType.None with same error.  I tried removing the , EventTrackingEnabled and still same error.  I did notice that i was wrong and did not have a try catch around my getRequesterType method, so i surrounded with just a General Exception catch and no errors were caught.  I also noticed that i had two Objects in the Main class as global objects, so i added a Dispose method to set those objects to null and made that method public for ASP to call before setting the rdCustomObj = nothing.

Comment: I don't know if this could be part of the problem or not, but in order to overwrite the dll after recompiling, i have to stop IIS and the WebService.  If I don't I get an error trying to overwrite that the file is in use.  Is that typical?  This also answers the back of the mind question that IIS has to be restarted following the overwirte of the dll.

Comment: Its been a few years since I have done any classic ASP, but I rember that being typical that once the Com object dll is loaded into the IIS address space, it never gets unloaded and u have to restart the IIS process to overwrite it.

Comment: Ok, so I was finally able to answer my own question.  I was able to deduce that my Method getRequesterType was the culprit by creating a simple method that just returned text with out using managed classes / code.  I was able to resolve the issue, by creating a Dispose method for my sql data class that properly closes all of the global variables for that class.  I then dispose and set to null in the getRequesterType Method and no more errors and i am consistently returning requester type as expected. Thanks for your efforts user957902

Comment: OP if you found an answer to your question (as you stated) please post it here and accept this answer ;)